# Footer is repeating in magento theme

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce

I am working on a magento theme(purchased from themeforest). When I installed this theme it shows the footer area twice and internal scroll in the webpage. 
Here is the online link :

```
http://204.236.236.249/magento/
```

Please help how can I solve this problem ?

Answer (score 2):

check your app/design/frontend/default/your-theme-name/templates/page/2column-left.phtml file.

there you may have called `$this->getChildHtml('footer')` **twice**.

Comment: Its called only one time over there.  <div id="yt_footerwrap" class="wrap">
            <div class="container">
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('footer') ?>
            </div>
        </div>

Comment: hey i have just checked your url, its gone.

Comment: I have removed this single $this->getChildHtml('footer') ?>  from this page. But it working on single page only not on all pages.

Comment: check out your all .phtml file under app/design/frontend/default/your-theme-name/templates/page/ and cms pages in admin for above code repetition.